Validation error for LLM chain while loading the model
I'm designing a PDF Q/A chatbot using OPEN AI but got some issues. I have already visited other stack overflow questions but none of them helped me.
Code:
from langchain_community.document_loaders import PyPDFLoader, DirectoryLoader
from langchain.prompts import PromptTemplate
from langchain_community.embeddings import HuggingFaceEmbeddings
from langchain_community.vectorstores import FAISS
from langchain_community.llms import CTransformers
from langchain.chains import RetrievalQA
from langchain.embeddings.openai import OpenAIEmbeddings
import openai
import os

os.environ['OPENAI_API_KEY'] = "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"

DB_FAISS_PATH = 'vectorstore/db_faiss'

custom_prompt_template = """Use the following pieces of information to answer the user's question.
If you don't know the answer, just say that you don't know, don't try to make up an answer.

Context: {context}
Question: {question}

Only return the helpful answer below and nothing else.
Helpful answer:
"""

def set_custom_prompt():
    """
    Prompt template for QA retrieval for each vectorstore
    """
    prompt = PromptTemplate(template=custom_prompt_template,
                            input_variables=['context', 'question'])
    return prompt

# Retrieval QA Chain
def retrieval_qa_chain(llm, prompt, db):
    qa_chain = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(llm=llm,
                                           chain_type='stuff',
                                           retriever=db.as_retriever(search_kwargs={'k': 2}),
                                           return_source_documents=True,
                                           chain_type_kwargs={'prompt': prompt}
                                           )
    return qa_chain

# Loading the model
def load_llm():
    llm = openai.chat.completions.create(
        model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
        temperature=0,
        max_tokens=2000,
        messages=[
            {"role": "system", "content": "You are a helpful assistant designed to output JSON."},
            {"role": "user", "content": "Who won the world series in 2020?"}
        ]
    )
    embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings(model='text-embedding-ada-002',
                                  model_kwargs={'device': 'cpu'})
    new_db = FAISS.load_local(DB_FAISS_PATH, embeddings, allow_dangerous_deserialization=True)
    return llm, new_db

# QA Model Function
def qa_bot():
    llm, new_db = load_llm()
    qa_prompt = set_custom_prompt()
    qa = retrieval_qa_chain(llm=llm,
                            prompt=qa_prompt,
                            db=new_db)
    return qa

# Output function
def final_result(query):
    qa_result = qa_bot()
    response = qa_result({'query': query})
    print(response)
    return response

# Interaction without ChainLit
def start_bot():
    chain = qa_bot()
    print("Starting the bot...")
    print("Hi, Welcome to Medical Bot. What is your query?")

    while True:
        user_input = input("> ")
        response = chain(user_input)
        answer = response["result"]
        sources = response["source_documents"]

        if sources:
            answer += f"\nSources:" + str(sources)
        else:
            answer += "\nNo sources found"

        print(answer)

# Start the bot
if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_bot()


Error:

pydantic.v1.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 2 validation errors for
LLMChain llm   instance of Runnable expected
(type=type_error.arbitrary_type; expected_arbitrary_type=Runnable) llm
instance of Runnable expected (type=type_error.arbitrary_type;
expected_arbitrary_type=Runnable)

This chatbot is suppose to answer from the pdfs. Any help will be highly appriciated.
